# python variable reassignment inside nested loops not working

Tags: python

I am attempting to reassign variables inside nested for loops. I'd like to get the index for the number 6 inside a list of lists, but it's not working. Why isn't it working and how can I fix it?

Here's the code:

```
row = 0
col = 0
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 4, 6, 9]]
for i in range(len(a)):
  for j in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][j] == 6:
      row = i # expect row = 1
      col = j # expect col = 3
print(row) # prints 0
print(col) # prints 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row` and `col` are not updated because the `if` statement is never executed. The loop with the `j` variable needs to be based on the length of `a[i]`, not `a`, as `a` has a length of two while the lists inside it each have a length of 5. With that restriction, it's not finding the `6` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line should iterate over the second dimension, so

```
  for j in range(len(a[i])):
```